# WPF custom control looking weird on deployment

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I use a custom numericUpDown control in my WPF application which works fine in my local development environment. However when i deploy my application the control looks strange, to be more specific, all the elements within the control seem to be in place but without the styles. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please state all pertinent differences between development environment and deployment environment (operating system, etc). One thing I've discovered is that the Windows theme has an effect on styles. Where are your styles defined? How do you include them into the app resources?

Comment: I agree with @Andre Luss and may have asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692596/wpf-windows-program-displays-in-large-fonts-but-only-on-one-pc) with a couple of good answers. If this does not help please post an image of your problem.